# URL Rewrite for images

Tags: php, .htaccess

My `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule     ^the-image-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9+]+)/?$  images/userfolder/$1/$2 [NC,L] #Loading Images
```

And in my PHP page

```
<img src='./the-image-$username-$image_id' alt='User Image' />
```

My aim is to load the image for each user based upon his username and Image ID.

The username is stored under `$username` and Image ID under `$image_id` variables. And the images will be located under `images/userfolder/username/image.jpg`

But the images are not getting loaded. What is the error in my syntax?

Note: The Image ID variable holds both the image name and it' extension. Example : `1.jpg`

Comment: Are you doing the redirect to a relative path? Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: @SuryaS Use the absolute path. What will the relative path be relative to?

Comment: @JakeGould: That message I found only in the Apache Error Log located in "Apache/logs/error.log". Anyway the problem is now resolved :) Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
RewriteRule  ^the-image-([^-]+)-([^-]+)/?$  images/userfolder/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^the-image-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9+]+)/?$
```

The forward slash at the end is not escaped. Try changing the regex this way

```
^the-image-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9+]+)\/?$
```

Or you can just remove it if you never expect any forward slash after the $image_id

```
^the-image-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9+]+)$
```